# Insert CRLF at the end of each line

Tags: java

I am reading a text file and finding a pattern and printing it. The issue is whenever I run my code, it finds the pattern but somehow I am not able to get 0D in the text. I am able to insert 0A.

Below is my code:

```
   File xmlFile = new File("location of file");
  Reader fleReader = new FileReader(xmlFile);
  BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
StringBuilder sb = newStringBuilder();
 String line = bufReader.readLine();
 while (line!=null){
     sb.append(line).append("\n");
     line = bufReader.readLine();
    }

  String xml2String = sb.toString();
  System.setProperty("line.separator","\n\r");
 final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(pattern that i want to match, Pattern.DOTALL);
 final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(xml2String);
 while(matcher.find()){
 String matchedpattern = matcher.group(0):
  System.out.println(matchedpattern);
}}}
```

Expected result should have 0d0a in the Hex result. That means CRLF should be implemented after each line.

Comment: So, you append `\n` and then you expect to find `\r` there as well? Where should that come from?

Comment: if I am not wrong, I am putting "\r\n" in  System.setProperty("line.separator","\n\r");

Comment: Yes, you do that and it obviously won't manipulate all Strings which contain `\n`. That wouldn't even make the slightest sense.

Comment: I changed the sb.append(line).append("\n"); to sb.append(line).append("\n\r"); and it worked. Thanks a lot for help!!

Comment: It works because you now append the line break you expect. If that is what you're looking for, thats fine, but you should delete the line `System.setProperty("line.separator","\n\r");` it doesn't help you in your task here and might cause trouble somewhere else, because it sets the line separator for the whole application, not just this method/class.